# Group cells based on certain criteria

Tags: excel

In this spreadsheet, I have the following data that consists of more than 600 rows:

[image]

How I want this data to be transformed is through the following (separated by semi-colons)

[image]

How can this best be done efficiently without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) If you have access to `UNIQUE` and `FILTER`:

1. `D1 = TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A9))` (*will automatically create headers of unique values*)
2. `D2 = TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE, FILTER($B:$B,$A:$A=D$1))` (*drag over to right as needed*)

---

### 2) If you only have access to `TEXTJOIN`

1. Manually get your list of unique values in `Column A` as headers
2. `D2 = TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$9=E1,$B$1:$B$9,""))` (*Confirm with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  and drag over to right as needed*)

---

### 3) If you don't have access to any of the functions above

1. Manually get your list of unique values in `Column A` as headers
2. `D2 =CONCAT(IF($A$1:$A$9=E1,$B$1:$B$9&"; ",""))` (*Confirm with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  and drag over to right as needed*)

---

*Cell references to all solutions above apply to this photo. Notice that the 3rd solution that you will have to use leaves you with a trailing `;` although this can be removed with `LEFT` if absolutely necessary.*

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the Unique and Filter equations.

Comment: Do you have `TEXTJOIN`?

Comment: I don't have that one either. I just have the desktop version of excel.

Comment: It's the version of excel you have that is limiting your functions, not because it's desktop. Anyhow, I have updated with a solution using function you **should** have access to (`solution 3`)

Comment: Got it, I appreciate your help with this!